# Django Python can not upload directory with large quantity of files

Tags: ajax, django-file-upload

I am trying to upload a directory with large number of dicom files using Django and JQuery ajax. Each file size is not more than 600kb. I can upload 200 files at a time. If I increase the number of files (tried to upload 14000 files), it doesn’t work. The site gets stuck and it’s not showing any error. Can anyone please help me with this problem? I have attached my code below. Thanks in advance.

**View.py:**

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f,filePath):
  with open(filePath+'/'+f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)

def UploadScanView(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     form = create_scan_form(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        scan = form.save(commit=False)
        scan.project_id = form.cleaned_data.get('project_id')

        directory_name = request.POST.get('directories')
        json_to_dictionary = json.loads(directory_name)
        print(json_to_dictionary)
        for upload_file in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/'+os.path.dirname(json_to_dictionary[upload_file.name])
            print(file_path)
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                handle_uploaded_file(upload_file, file_path)
            else:
                os.makedirs(file_path)
                handle_uploaded_file(upload_file,file_path)
         return render(request, 'fileupload/basic_upload/scan_upload.html', {'form': form})
  else:
    form = create_scan_form()  
  return render(request, 'fileupload/basic_upload/scan_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**HTML and JQuery:**

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        /*fileupload div*/
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#my-file").on('change',function(e){ //submit(function(e){
              $("#file-wrap p").text('Now click on Upload button');
            });
          $("#my-form").on('submit',function(e){ //submit(function(e){
             files = document.querySelector("#my-file").files;
             var directories = {}
                for (var file of files) {
                    file.webkitRelativePath
                    directories[file.name] = file.webkitRelativePath
                }
            directories = JSON.stringify(directories);
            document.querySelector("#directories").value = directories
            var eventType = $(this).attr("method"); // get method type for #my-form
            var eventLink = $(this).attr("action"); // get action link for #my-form
            //alert(directories);
                //////
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
            $.ajax({
                    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                    type: eventType,
                    url: eventLink,
                    //data: new FormData(this), // IMPORTANt
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    // this part is progress bar
                    xhr: function () {
                            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                    var percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total;
                                    percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                                    $('.myprogress').text(percentComplete + '%');
                                    $('.myprogress').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                                }
                            }, false);
                            return xhr;
                        },
                    success: function(getResult) {
                        $('#my-form')[0].reset(); // reset form
                        $("#file-wrap p").html('Drag and drop file here'); // change wrap message
                        }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

        /*fileupload div*/

    </script>
```

```html
<form id="my-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'fileupload:upload_scan' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!--independentSub-->
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="user_form" class="container">
          
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="project_id">
                    {{ form.project_id|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>

            <!--fileupload div-->
            <div id="independentSubDiv" class="row">
                <div id="file-wrap" class="form-group col-sm-6" >
                    <p>Drag and drop file here</p>
                    <input id="my-file" type="file" name="file" multiple webkitdirectory directory draggable="true">
                    <input type="text" id="directories" name="directories" hidden />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="padding-left: initial" id="independentSubDiv" class="form-group col-sm-7" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="progress form-group col-sm-7" style="padding-left: initial" id="progressDiv" >
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success myprogress " role="progressbar">0%</div>
            </div>

       </div>
    </form>
```